# Microsoft Graph API no longer returns name and lastModifiedDateTime

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I've been using the Microsoft Graph API's [recent items endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-recent?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and until yesterday it was returning the file `name` and `lastModifiedDateTime` as it is supposed to per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0).

However, now responses do not contain `name` or `lastModifiedDateTime`, and no longer seem to order by `lastModifiedDateTime` (for obvious reasons).

Here is the endpoint I am using - `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent?$select=name,id,remoteItem,lastModifiedDateTime,webUrl&$top=50&$orderBy=lastModifiedDateTime desc`

Here's the response:

```
{
   "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
   "id":"01YGW3HF7E7M4TYF74AZAZBXWG7BXHJDI5",
   "remoteItem":{
      "createdDateTime":"2020-09-08T09:54:15Z",
      "id":"01YGW3HF7E7M4TYF74AZAZBXWG7BXHJDI5",
      "lastModifiedDateTime":"2020-09-15T05:18:40Z",
      "name":"Document.docx",
      "size":11381,
      "webDavUrl":"https://firmationpersonal-my.sharepoint.com/personal/utkarsh_firmationpersonal_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/Document.docx",
      "webUrl":"https://firmationpersonal-my.sharepoint.com/personal/utkarsh_firmationpersonal_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B3C39FBE4-FC17-4106-90DE-C6F86E748D1D%7D&file=Document.docx&action=default&mobileredirect=true",
      "createdBy":{
         "user":{
            "displayName":"NotAdmin Dalal",
            "email":"utkarsh@firmationpersonal.onmicrosoft.com"
         }
      },
      "file":{
         "mimeType":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
      },
      "fileSystemInfo":{
         "createdDateTime":"2020-09-08T09:54:15Z",
         "lastModifiedDateTime":"2020-09-15T05:18:40Z",
         "lastAccessedDateTime":"2020-09-15T06:57:48Z"
      },
      "lastModifiedBy":{
         "user":{
            "displayName":"Utkarsh Dalal",
            "email":"utkarshdalal@firmationpersonal.onmicrosoft.com"
         }
      },
      "parentReference":{
         "driveId":"b!BqfSC_mYxUKYaPxJ673ZaLB_EByxRr1Jkipu7nqJIUrSVsVcfbmBSbJAp1sPfpJ4",
         "driveType":"business",
         "id":"01YGW3HF56Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ"
      },
      "shared":{
         
      },
      "sharepointIds":{
         "listId":"5cc556d2-b97d-4981-b240-a75b0f7e9278",
         "listItemId":"1",
         "listItemUniqueId":"3c39fbe4-fc17-4106-90de-c6f86e748d1d",
         "siteId":"0bd2a706-98f9-42c5-9868-fc49ebbdd968",
         "siteUrl":"https://firmationpersonal-my.sharepoint.com/personal/utkarsh_firmationpersonal_onmicrosoft_com",
         "webId":"1c107fb0-46b1-49bd-922a-6eee7a89214a"
      }
   }
}
```

**Update**: I was able to work around this by making some modifications. The response always seemed to include `remoteItem`, so I extract `name` and `lastModifiedDateTime` from the `remoteItem` dict.
I also order by `remoteItem/lastModifiedDateTime` instead of just `lastModifiedDateTime`.

My code in Python:

```
endpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent?" \
               "$select=name,id,remoteItem,lastModifiedDateTime,webUrl" \
               "&$top=50&$orderBy=remoteItem/lastModifiedDateTime desc"

response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=header)
events = json.loads(response.content)
for recent_activity in events['value']:
     # Merge the remoteItem dict and the recent_activity dict because sometimes the data is nested in remoteItem
     recent_activity = {**recent_activity, **recent_activity.get('remoteItem', {})}
     activity_modified_datetime = datetime.strptime(recent_activity['lastModifiedDateTime'],
                                                               '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
     name = recent_activity['name']
```

Just a workaround until this is fixed - which may be never.

Comment: The above query wasn't working for me either. Good workaround :)

Comment: BTW, this below query works for me. But, its telling me that $orderby is not supported. See that if this helps: 

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$select=name,id,remoteItem,lastModifiedDateTime,webUrl&$top=50

Comment: Are you still looking for help here?

Comment: For the moment, my workaround works, but I worry that it will stop working once the API goes back to returning responses as documented.